# `this.add.image` works as expected whereas subclass of `Phaser.GameObjects.Image` moves the image up a bit, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to put a health bar on top of a player, which looks like the one below

[image]

Here is the code,

```
  create() {
    let player = this.add.image(100, 100, 'elves', 'blue_idle_0').setOrigin(0);
    this.add.rectangle(100, 100, player.width, player.height, 0xff0000, .3).setOrigin(0);
    console.log(player.width, player.height);

    let bar = new Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics(this);
    this.add.existing(bar);
    this.x = 100 + 10;
    this.y = 100 - 5 - 16;
    bar.fillStyle(0x000000);
    bar.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 80, 16);

    bar.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 2, this.y + 2, 76, 12);

    bar.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    let d = 76
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 2, this.y + 2, d, 12);
  }
}
```

which works as expected.

I created a player using 'elves' texture borrowed from the official example repo.

I put an extra red rectangle to indicate the top left corner of the player is located at (100, 100). the gap between the bottom of the bar and the top of the rectangle equals 5.

However, when I encapsulate all the stuff above in class `Player` which extends `GameObjects.Image`, I got a bug.

Here is the code.

```js
class Player extends Phaser.GameObjects.Image {
  constructor(scene, x, y, texture, frame) {
    super(scene, x, y, texture, frame);
    this.setOrigin(0);
    scene.add.existing(this).setOrigin(0);
    scene.add.rectangle(x, y, this.width, this.height, 0xff0000, .3).setOrigin(0);
    console.log(this.width, this.height);

    let bar = new Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics(scene);
    scene.add.existing(bar);
    this.x = x + 10;
    this.y = y - 5 - 16;
    bar.fillStyle(0x000000);
    bar.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 80, 16);

    // Health
    bar.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 2, this.y + 2, 76, 12);

    bar.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    let d = 76
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 2, this.y + 2, d, 12);
  }
}

class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'BootScene'
    });
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/master/public/assets/animations/'
    this.load.atlas('elves', 'elves-craft-pixel.png', 'elves-craft-pixel.json');
  }

  create() {
    new Player(this, 100, 100, 'elves', 'blue_idle_0');
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  backgroundColor: '0xD3D3DC',
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

both the bar and the rectangle stay at where they are supposed to be

[image]

only the player moves up a bit.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, the extra alterations you made to `this.x` and `this.y`, should have been done on the health bar:

```
    // not needed to add here the offset
    this.x = x + 10;
    this.y = y - 5 - 16;
```

I just added the extra values to the health bar positions *(I just added-up the offset for the position to the offset needed for the health-bar, to make the code shorter)*:

```
    // the offset is only needed on the health-bar
    ...
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 10 , this.y - 21, 80, 16);
    ...
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 12, this.y - 19, 76, 12);
    ...
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 12, this.y -19, d, 12);
```

***Here an adaptation of your Code:***

```js
class Player extends Phaser.GameObjects.Image {
  constructor(scene, x, y, texture, frame) {
    super(scene, x, y, texture, frame);
    this.setOrigin(0);
    scene.add.existing(this).setOrigin(0);
    scene.add.rectangle(x, y, this.width, this.height, 0xff0000, .3).setOrigin(0);
    console.log(this.width, this.height);

    let bar = new Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics(scene);
    scene.add.existing(bar);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y ;
    bar.fillStyle(0x000000);
    bar.fillRect(this.x +10 , this.y-21, 80, 16);

    // Health
    bar.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 12, this.y - 19, 76, 12);

    bar.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    let d = 76
    bar.fillRect(this.x + 12, this.y -19, d, 12);
  }
}

class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'BootScene'
    });
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/master/public/assets/animations/'
    this.load.atlas('elves', 'elves-craft-pixel.png', 'elves-craft-pixel.json');
  }

  create() {
    new Player(this, 100, 100, 'elves', 'blue_idle_0');
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  backgroundColor: '0xD3D3DC',
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```